# Codeigniter Cart cannot add items

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, shopping-cart

So i'm trying to create an application with cart and when i tried adding the item, it's not working. By the way i already have a working cart application that's why i'm wondering why it's not working. I almost copied everything from the working one. here's the code

Cart Controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Cart extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('cart');
}

public function add_to_cart(){

    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    if($this->cart->contents()){
        foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $item){
            if ($item['id']==$id){
                $data = array('rowid'=>$item['rowid'],
                    'qty'=>++$item['qty']);
                $process = $this->cart->update($data);
            }
            else{
                $data = array(
                    'id'=>$id,
                    'qty'=>1,                       
                    'name' => $this->get_data->get_value('product_name','products','product_id', $id),
                    'price' => $this->get_data->get_value('product_price','products','product_id', $id)
                    );
                $process = $this->cart->insert($data);
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        $data = array('id'=>$id,
                    'qty' =>1,
                    'name' => $this->get_data->get_value('product_name','products','product_id', $id),
                    'price' => $this->get_data->get_value('product_price','products','product_id', $id),
                    );
                    $process = $this->cart->insert($data);
    }


    if($process){
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Successful');
        redirect('products');
    }
    else{
        $this->session->set_flashdata('failed', 'Failed');
        redirect('products');
        //var_dump($process);
    }
}
```

Here's the button

```
<div class="button pull-right" style="margin-top: 10px;"><a href="<?php echo base_url().'cart/add_to_cart/'.$row->product_id;?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>Add to Cart</a></div>
```

I really can't see the problem, i'm using session database, the sess_us_database is already TRUE. I tried using `var_dump($process)` and it's false, i tried `var_dump($data)` and the data seems to be fine but the insert part isn't working. Any idea guys? it would be a big help for me, thank you.

Comment: You just need to overwrite the default rule of cart product name, you can add this $this->cart->product_name_rules = '[:print:]'; $this->cart->insert($cart_array());
  line from where (In your controller) your products added to the cart

Answer (score 12, accepted):

CI Default cart allows only `alpha-numeric, dashes, underscores, colons or periods` in Product Name and If Price of product is `0` then also it will not add the product to cart.

Please check them first.

Comment: Thank you so much! so the problem was the name of the product has a single qoute

Comment: Thanks!! This solved my problem, I had products with price 0.

Comment: Solved my problem too. Had a '-' in name. This is pretty silly imo :\ Thanks!

Comment: to note, you can disable this if you want, simply extend the Cart class with your own MY_Cart class and set the property 'public $product_name_safe' to FALSE. Alternatively modify the regex in the 'public $product_name_rules' property. Helps to look through the code!

Comment: if i want to use alpha-numeric, dashes, underscores, colons or periods then what should i do ?
OR 
how can i manage this in CI Default cart

Comment: Please check @Samus comment above

Comment: Brilliant! turns out my item names had brackets in them, I've had to replace them to get it to work

Answer (score 0):

A nice way to change this variable is putting a MY_Cart.php on your application\libraries\MY_Cart.php with this code:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Cart extends CI_Cart {

    var $product_name_rules = '[:print:]';

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you forgot on of the following :

// Does the $items array contain an id, quantity, price, and name?  These are required

1 - price must be number and greater than 0 .
2 - name must be on alpha 
3 - quantity be number and greater than 0 . 
4 - must set id

and if you need to add any name you can remove this code :

```
if ($this->product_name_safe && ! preg_match('/^['.$this-product_name_rules.']+$/i'.(UTF8_ENABLED ? 'u' : ''), $items['name']))
    {
        log_message('error', 'An invalid name was submitted as the product name: '.$items['name'].' The name can only contain alpha-numeric characters, dashes, underscores, colons, and spaces');
        return FALSE;
    }
```

> from system/libraries/Cart.php : line 227

Answer (score -1):

When product add into cart replace special character from product name.

Example: EKEN H9R / H9 Action Camera Ultra HD 4K / 25fps WiFi 2.0" 170D Underwater Waterproof Helmet Video Recording

```
// Trim special character from text
    public function trim_special_char($text)
    {
        $str = str_replace("(", '_:', $text);
        $str = str_replace(")", ':_', $str);
        $str = str_replace("/", '_slash', $str);
        $str = str_replace("+", '_plus', $str);
        $str = str_replace("&", '_and', $str);
        $str = str_replace("'", '_ss', $str);
        $str = str_replace("x", '_X', $str);
        $str = str_replace('"', '_cot', $str);

        return $str;
    }

    // Set special character from previous text
    public function set_special_char($text)
    {
        $str = str_replace('_:',  "(", $text);
        $str = str_replace(':_', ")", $str);
        $str = str_replace('_slash', "/", $str);
        $str = str_replace('_plus', "+", $str);
        $str = str_replace('_and', "&", $str);
        $str = str_replace('_ss', "'", $str);
        $str = str_replace('_X', "x", $str);
        $str = str_replace('_cot', '"', $str);

        return $str;
    }
```