# CodeIgniter cart not inserting data

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, cart

I'm fairly new to CI and I'm working on an e-commerce website. I am having problem adding products to the cart.

Below is my code both Jscript and controller. Problem is it's working perfectly fine in localhost but on server it doesn't.

Here is my code:

Ajax Request

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.add_cart a').on('click',function(e){
              e.preventDefault();
              var productid = $(this).data('productid');
              var productName = $(this).data('prdname');
              var productPrice  = $(this).data('prdprice');
              var productDp    = $(this).data('prddp');
              console.log(productDp);
              console.log(productid);
              console.log(productPrice);
               console.log(productName);
              $.ajax({
                url:"www.wesbiteurl/home/addToCart/",
                method:'POST',
                data:{id:productid, prdname:productName, 
     prdprice:productPrice, dp:productDp},
                success:function(data){
                  /*alert("product added to cart");*/
                  $('.msg').html(data);
                }
              });
            });
      });
```

This section working fine and I'm sending data from here.

In my controller

```
      public function addToCart(){
            $data = array(
                    'id'=>$this->input->post('id'),
                    'qty' =>1,
                    'price' =>$this->input->post('prdprice'),
                    'name'=>$this->input->post('prdname'),
                    'options' => array('prdDp' => $this->input->post('dp'))
                );

            //return var_dump($data);
            //array(5) { ["id"]=> string(2) "10" ["qty"]=> int(1) ["price"]=> string(2) "20" ["name"]=> string(18) "product name" ["options"]=> array(1) { ["prdDp"]=> string(90) "here link image" } }


                if($this->cart->insert($data)){
                    return var_dump($this->cart->contents());
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
        }
```

As you can see it's working fine before if statement, after that it's not working. This working fine in the localhost though.

Comment: return statement will not work with your ajax. just use ```echo json_encode($this->cart->contents())```

Comment: whats the `data`  in ajax response ? and `cart` in the controller is your model ? can you paste the insert function code here ?

Comment: @kishor10d its going to else statement ... if is not executing

Comment: @ArunpandianM data from product listing page ... cart is CI Library

Comment: @Racoon your insert function not returning `true` even the query is executed successfully thats why you are not getting answer show us your `insert function` from your model

Comment: it might be help : https://stackoverflow.com/a/28215632/2940521

Comment: print the `$this->cart->insert()` check whether its returning `last insert id`

Comment: can you echo "<pre>"; print_r($data), and paste here

Comment: @MuhammadAkberKhan tnx mate :) i had some special character in the name its working now tyvm ^^

Comment: Readers do not expect Shakespearean sonnets, but please make an effort to use real words here. Abbreviations to words like "what" and "thanks" are fine on Facebook, but not Stack Overflow. Keep it readable please!

Comment: Go give lecture somewhere else i am here for answer if you have share it or else skip it , in my word ZIP it. You see even with that so many people understand the issue and suggested me something or other unlike you who seeking only for attention here

Answer (score 2):

Thank you guys ^^
i had special character in my product name ...

this is the answer:

> it might be help :
>    https://stackoverflow.com/a/28215632/2940521

– [Muhammad Akber Khan 11 mins ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45583572/codeigniter-cart-not-inserting-data-solved#comment78126731_45583572)

Answer (score 0):

```
  $data = array(
                'id'=>$this->input->post('id'),
                'qty' =>1,
                'price' =>$this->input->post('prdprice'),
                'name'=>$this->input->post('prdname'),
                'options' => array('prdDp' => $this->input->post('dp'))
            );

$this->cart->insert($data);
$cart = $this->cart->contents();
if(!empty($cart)){
 echo print_r($cart);
}
```

Comment: its still going to else statement .... and on top of that cant check empty or not becz i want to update product in the cart every time this function is called.

Comment: Is your cart have items?

Comment: when you insert item then it will see or not?